# Missing item in pattern question

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

[image]

So I notice that the hexagon rises, so it should be A or B. But beyond that, I can't figure out why one of A or B would be correct and the other would not be.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! This appears to be a question from an outside source. Questions from other places can only be posted here if the source allows their questions to be shared on other platforms. If you are certain it is allowed to be posted her make sure to include the source in the question to give proper credit. You can also take the tour to get some guidance on how this site works (and get your 1st badge) from this link : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour . Hope you have fun here on PSE and maybe try making some puzzles of your own or looking at other peoples while you are here.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree: The only one with the right height is C. A and B are already above the level of the 4th image...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> [image]

The key is:

> Pay attention to the number of moves the circle makes counter-clockwise with each step. From the first image to the second, the circle moves one space. From the fourth to the fifth step, it makes four moves counter-clockwise. So now we need to find the missing piece that is two moves counter-clockwise from the second step, and consequently three moves clockwise from the fourth step. That would be tile B:
> [image]

Comment: Just looking at this again...the answer to this puzzle would also be the next pattern in the sequence!